# Neo4j for front end HTML

Tags: javascript, html, graph, neo4j, graph-databases

I've been checking out Neo4j and graph database and absolutely love the idea. I've been thinking is it possible to make an entire web page into a graph database. E.g. a div tag has a relationship  (or edge) to another `<div />` either by an event (click, mouseover, etc) or making up different relationships like `hides` or `deletes`.

I know of KnockoutJS which is good but not really what I’m looking for. I’m more of looking for converting a database into an HTML page entirely with events etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: Apart from event-driven JS MVC stuff like BackBone.js, I can recall only the Lift framework which composes interactions among components. Specifically, check "wiring" from their "Seven things" promo material. If you want to get your hands dirty with event processing, maybe a Drools product may help.

Comment: There is structr.org which is an open source CMS running on top of neo4j, and other approaches like lightbulb that is a CMS on top of the bulbflow python Server API.